# How to retrieve the data value and convert array to dictionary using power automate expression?

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerapps, power-automate

I have a form that sends data to a power automate flow. The output of the trigger for the flow is shown below.

[image]

How do I transform the data to output this format

```
{
    "Form ID": "67249",
    "Timezone": "America/Denver",
    "User Timezone": "America/Denver"
 }
```

So I can use property names to store the output in variables?

I tried using array index and it worked but when a field is omitted the index moves up and a wrong variable value is stored. Also tried using select and parse json but the action outputs a key which is one every object in the array. Select returned a result but not able to stored it in different varables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit clunky but you can do it like this ...

[image: Flow]

##### Explanation

**First**, I initialise an `Array` variable with a set of key value pairs.  It's not your data specifically but that doesn't matter.  It looks like this ...

```
[
  {
    "key": "Key 1",
    "value": "Value 1"
  },
  {
    "key": "Key 2",
    "value": "Value 2"
  },
  {
    "key": "Key 3",
    "value": "Value 3"
  },
  {
    "key": "Key 4",
    "value": "Value 4"
  },
  {
    "key": "Key 5",
    "value": "Value 5"
  }
]
```

**Second & third**, I initialise two empty variables of type `Object`.  There's a reason why I need a temp version which I'll explain a little later on.

**Fourth**, you need to loop through the array of key value pairs.  It's within that array that you're going to perform the magic.

**Fifth**, you need to use a `Set variable` operation and make sure it's assigned to the temp resulting object.

The expression within that step is ...

```
addProperty(variables('Resulting Object'), item()['key'], item()['value'])
```

... and the reason for needing the temp variable is because when using the `Set variable` operation, you can't self assign.  So basically, an expression cannot be used against the variable that you're setting.  You can see in the `addProperty` expression, we're referring to the non-temp resulting object variable, not the temp one.

**Sixth**, now transfer the temp object over to the main one.  We do this because the next time the loop comes around, it will refer to the main/non-temp object and retain all of the existing properties that we previously added.

**Finally**, this is the end result ...

```
{
  "Key 1": "Value 1",
  "Key 2": "Value 2",
  "Key 3": "Value 3",
  "Key 4": "Value 4",
  "Key 5": "Value 5"
}
```

***Note:** I set the concurrency on the loop to be 1 so as to preserve the order of the key value pairs.  You can choose to do this or not.*

Comment: Thank you so much Skin, this worked! I was having errors before but I had to initialise the objects with an empty object "{}".

Comment: Please @SKin do you have any idea on how to get the values where some of the keys have array embedded in them?

Comment: There's always a way.  Can you enhance your question to include an example where that is the case?  Also, provide an example of what you want the output to look like when the value of the property is an array.

Comment: Thanks @Skin you have been amazing! I appreciate your help. I found away around that issue and just had to remove the square brackets from the keys.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative way in one-step.

```
json(
    replace( replace( replace( replace( 
        string( outputs('Compose') ),
    '[{"key":', '{'),  ']', ''), '},{"key":', ','), ',"value"', '')
)
```

Convert the json array to a string, do a few string replacements, then back to json again.

#### Flow edit

[image: Flow edit]

#### Flow result

[image: Flow result]